# Multiply dataframe rows depends on value in this row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [69, 77, 88],
                   'col2': ['bar34', 'barf30', 'barfoo29'],
                   'col3': [4, 2, 5]})
print(df, '\n')
```

```
   col1      col2  col3
0    69     bar34     4
1    77    barf30     2
2    88  barfoo29     5
```

I need multiply rows depends on value in 'col3'. Desired output:

```
    col1      col2  col3
0     69     bar34     4
1     69     bar34     4
2     69     bar34     4
3     69     bar34     4
4     77    barf30     2
5     77    barf30     2
6     88  barfoo29     5 
7     88  barfoo29     5 
8     88  barfoo29     5 
9     88  barfoo29     5 
10    88  barfoo29     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html#pandas-index-repeat) then [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex)

```
df = df.set_index(df.col3)

print(
    df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.col3))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

---

```
# suggested by @anky,

df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.col3)]
```

---

```
    col1      col2  col3
0     69     bar34     4
1     69     bar34     4
2     69     bar34     4
3     69     bar34     4
4     77    barf30     2
5     77    barf30     2
6     88  barfoo29     5
7     88  barfoo29     5
8     88  barfoo29     5
9     88  barfoo29     5
10    88  barfoo29     5
```

Comment: Actually you donot need to set_index: `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['col3'])].reset_index(drop=True)` would also work since `index.repeat` repeats the existing indices

Answer (score 0):

I have only one solution, but i'm pretty sure it's not efficient at all.

```
import numpy as np


# Get columns list
cols = df.columns.to_list()

# Loop for each row to multiply
for index, row in df.iterrows():

   # Loop for each new row we get
   full_array = []
   for new_row in range(row['col3']):
      row_lst = [row[col_name] for col_name in cols]
      full_array.append(row_lst)
   numpy_data = np.array(full_array)

   # Drop used row
   df = df.drop([index])

   # Creating mini_df
   mini_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy_data, columns=columns)

   # Concat with main dataframe
   df = pd.concat([df, mini_df], ignore_index=True)
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

```
    col1      col2  col3
0     69     bar34     4
1     69     bar34     4
2     69     bar34     4
3     69     bar34     4
4     77    barf30     2
5     77    barf30     2
6     88  barfoo29     5 
7     88  barfoo29     5 
8     88  barfoo29     5 
9     88  barfoo29     5 
10    88  barfoo29     5
```